# How to repair these errors related to environment variable?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

I'm trying to migrate an oracle database to postgresql, I run the ora2pg command and i get these errors:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ora2pg

DBI connect('host=localhost;sid=XE;port=1521','HR',...) 
failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var or PATH (Windows) 
and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1/Ora2Pg.pm 
line 1491.
FATAL: -1 ... ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var or PATH 
(Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.
Aborting export...
```

This step is important to start the migration of the database knowing that I configured `ORACLE_HOME` variable such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: That error message tells you to check more than just environment variables, etc.

Comment: Please don't include photographs of errors, those aren't searchable, include the text of the error message to your question.  I know it's tedious to have to retype it out, but it makes things easier for everyone, including yourself.

Comment: @EricLeschinski It looks like that can just be copied and pasted. It appears to be cropped from a screenshot of a graphical terminal. *Khadhri Hamza*: If you select text in the a terminal window, you can then middle-click to paste the selection. Or you can copy it with Ctrl+Shift+C (because Ctrl+C is special in a terminal) or by right-clicking and clicking Copy, and then you can paste it with Ctrl+V as usual. When you **[edit]** your question, you can paste in what you copied, then select that text you pasted and press Ctrl+K (or click the **{}** button) to format it so it will be readable.

Comment: Eri  you are right but i want u to know that it's my first time that i publish something here, well i'm still learning and thanks for mentioning that to me..

Comment: Check the `NLS_LANG` environment variable. Example `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` or  `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`

Comment: what your `echo $ORACLE_HOME`?..

Comment: @Vao Tsun: 
root@ubuntu:~# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

Comment: hm, and what's `sed '1491,1499!d' /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1/Ora2Pg.pm` ?..

Comment: @Dmitry Demin: AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Comment: @Vao Tsun: 
 'AutoInactiveDestroy_=> 1,
  }
 );

 # Check for connection failure
 if (!$dbh) {
  $self->logit("FATAL: $DBI::err ... $DBI::errstr\n", 0, 1);
 }'

Comment: right - and what si in oracle instance logs?.. basically it cant `OCIEnvNlsCreate`, but the reason is not clear from your quotes - check server side - is oracle running at all?..

Comment: @Vao Tsun:
' oracle-xe.service - LSB: _Oracle 11g Express Edition_
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/oracle-xe; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: **active (running)** '

Comment: and logs?.. any erros?..

Comment: @Vao Tsun: could u please show me the full path of  the log file ?

Comment: `lsnrctl status instance_name` to show listener logs - check em first as you cant CONNECT I believe

Comment: @vao tsun: `root@ubuntu:~# lsnrctl status xe 
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER 
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                17-OCT-2017 03:32:04
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 18 min. 28 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE `

Comment: @vao: Listener Parameter File   `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ubuntu/listener/alert/log.xml
The command completed successfully`

Comment: so check the /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ubuntu/listener/alert/log.xml?..

Comment: @vao: no errors  :/